# Add path to .zshrc without $path, all command not found

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I add

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql"
```

to my `.zshrc` file, forgot `$PATH`. Now all the command not found, including `vim`, so I cannot access the `.zshrc` now. How I can fix it?

Comment: `vim` is probably placed at `/usr/bin/vim`.

Comment: Once you've got it open in vim, be sure to set `PATH` to dirs, not the executables (eg, mysql) themselves.

Comment: @MicahElliott It seems unlikely that anything would install a binary directly in `/usr/local/`; `/usr/local/mysql` probably *is* a directory.

Comment: You can also start any other shell, since they won't source `.zshrc` and clear your path. `/bin/sh` is pretty much guaranteed to exist.